# Fragment's Actionbar doesn't work when came back from another Activity sometimes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an `Activity` on which I am stacking two `Fragments` one at a time, when the second `Fragment` is visible and on click of some `View` I am launching another `Activity` and when I press back from there it will show the second `Fragment` but it doesn't update the `ActionBar` instead it will show the `ActionBar` of first `Fragment`.

Also, I am Overriding `onResume()` in the First `Activity` in which I am calling `onResume()` of visible `Fragment`. I am updating the `ActionBar` inside `onResume()` of the `Fragment`. Everything is getting called properly but still not updating the `ActionBar`.

Comment: have you called `invalidateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: Two things. As @zipc said, do you call 'invalidateOptionsMenu'. And sometime people forget to call super. Check both. And perhaps you should post you code for us to help you.

Comment: I tried using `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`, but still its not refreshing `ActionBar` sometimes.